# jQuery click to change color is working but something went wrong change font family

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a change color and font-family using the following code. Color is changing but the `font-family` is not changing. What I'm missing here? How should I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click",".selectableColor", function(){
      var tColor = $(this).attr("data-color"); 
    $('.change').css('color','#'+tColor+'');
  });
  $("body").on("click",".fontBox", function(){
      var tStyle = $(this).attr("data-style"); 
    $('.change').css('font-family', tStyle); 
  });
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="change_area_header" style="overflow: hidden; outline: currentcolor none medium;" tabindex="2">
      <div class="selectableColor" style="background-color:#ffebee" data-color="ffebee"></div>
      <div class="selectableColor" style="background-color:#ffcdd2" data-color="ffcdd2"></div> 
    </div>
    <!--Font Family-->
    <div class="change_area_header" style="overflow: hidden; outline: currentcolor none medium;" tabindex="4">
      <div class="fontBox" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;" data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif;">MontSerrat</div>
      <div class="fontBox" style="font-family: 'Aleo', serif;" data-style="'Aleo', serif;">Aleo</div>
      <div class="fontBox" style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;" data-style="'Raleway', sans-serif;">Raleway</div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/GzRMrO)** from *codepen.io*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons in the font-selectors as

From

```
data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif;"
```

To

```
data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif"
```

which becomes,

```
<!–– ... -->
 <div class="fontBox" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;" data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif">MontSerrat</div>
<!–– ... -->
```

Pen : https://codepen.io/ijasnijas/pen/wNvPXa

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `;` end of the `data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif;"`

Use :
`data-style="'Montserrat', sans-serif"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape characters. You statement converts to

`$('.change').css('font-family', ''Montserrat', sans-serif;')`

Something as simple as `$('.change').css('font-family', 'Segoe UI')` works in your example.

Also instead of having `data-style="'Raleway', sans-serif;"` you could only have the font name `data-fontname="Raleway"` and prepare the font chain in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe your thoughts about problem-solving is not true. I saw your codes. why you bind the click action on the `body`? you can select exact tag by using jQuery and then bind the action callback to it.

Also, you could declare some `CSS` classes not using inline code in `HTML` and you can add or remove classes to markup not assigning directly the styles property to the selected element. It's not safe because it is not debuggable. Just like you see you have a little and simple issue that you cannot track and fix it.

I proffer clean your code like below, I write to you a little sample then you complete your whole project by using this sample:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  var resultEl = $('.result');
  $('.blue').on('click', function(){
    resultEl.removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
  });
  $('.red').on('click', function(){
    resultEl.removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.result {
  font: normal 20px arial;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.blue {
  color: #f00;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  color: #00f;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">The Result of color and font</div>
<div class="blue">color&font</div>
<div class="red">color&font</div>
```